# How I can create a simple React component rendered as a <div> which takes a text value and a foreground color as input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in the world of React and after see tutorials and made some codes I wanted to know if I can add attributes like value and color to a div. I mean, How I can return Hello World with color. The follow is an example:

```
<div style="color: red;">Hello World!</div>
```

I tried with constructor function, but I can't render the color and the value of "Hello World!

Comment: inline style should be passed as an object with camelCase properties. see: [React: DOM elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it provides no value

Answer (score 2):

In a JSX file you'd use `<div style={{color: 'red'}}>Hello World!</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class for this.

```js
function Example() {
  return (
    <div className="red">
      Hello world!
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Or, if you're passing props into another component, you can still use this method. Just pass the colour as a prop, and then use `className={color}`.

```js
function Example() {
  return <Hello color="red" />
}

function Hello({ color }) {
  return (
    <div className={color}>
      Hello world!
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you man. The code run in VSC and in the console, but in the VPL doesn't want to run, I'm still trying.

Comment: What is "VPL"? I looked up some acronyms but I'm not any closer to understanding :) "Vancouver Public Library", perhaps?

Comment: It's a virtual programming lab, in other words is a virtual private LAN of the company.

Answer (score 0):

You could create sommething like this, where you pass in the `value` and `color` as props.

```js
const Label = ({ value, color }) => {
  return <div style={{ color: color }}>{value}</div>;
};
```

You can use it like so

```js
export function Preview() {
  return <Label value={"Solution"} color={"blue"} />;
}
```